# How can I resolve property conflicts in WPF when using Triggers?

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, wpf-controls, event-triggers

I am trying to change the background of a button but the problem is it has three states - IsEnabled, IsPressed and Clicked. In default state when I press the button the background changes and then when I click the button, the button animates but next time when I press the button, the background doesn't change but the Click (animation) works correctly, since there is a conflict on changing the similar resource.

Here is my source code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="myButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Name="myBorder"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="Stack" Background="DarkGray">
                             <Image x:Name="checkBoxImage" Width="40" Height="40" Source="NextPage.png"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Stack" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="Blue1"  KeyTime="0" />
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame Value="DarkGray1" KeyTime="0:0:0.4" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Stack" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a precedence issue. Animations have precedence over trigger-set values. You could either replace your trigger's setter with animations added to the `Enter`/`ExitActions` or try using [visual states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) and manage transitions that way (which probably works better because you do not really know what the `ExitAction` should animate to in all cases).